# Cipher(rsa-with-aes-128-cbc-sha) will use which SHA ?

Tags: ssl, openssl, cryptography, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

Which Digest(SHA1 or SHA256) will be used by Cipher(rsa-with-aes-128-cbc-sha  ) in TLS1.1 and TLS1.2?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

According to the official openssl  [website](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ciphers.html), SHA always means SHA1. You have to specify SHA256 explicitly, if you need to use SHA256.